# How can we refresh the part of the code in a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can we refresh the part of the code in a lightning component as like Rerender in VF page

Answer (score 7):

This is handled automatically by Lightning without the developer needing to take any special considerations. Whenever you set an attribute, it causes an aura:valueChange event, which eventually causes the appropriate elements to be refreshed. Here's a [demo](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/66488eb80292c7151f616ebe7d1b0a18) of something I wrote that shows client-side pagination and sorting. You don't need to specify a "reRender" target, because the platform will automatically update just the elements that need to be updated.

Comment: In your example, the file name is `PagingSortingController.cls` but the class name in it is `PagingSortingDemo`. It is failing to compile. I think you should change class name to match with the file name. +1 for sharing example with us.

Comment: @javanoob Thanks for that. It's been through a few revisions both in the gist and in my dev org. I fixed the code to match the file name.